# Get comments with reply count stored in the same collection mongodb aggregate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is the schema for comments and replies. Both comments and replies are separate documents in the same collection:

```
const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    postId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'posts', required: false},
    parentCommentId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'comments', required: false},
    likes: {type: Number, default: 0},
    liked_by: {
        type: [String],
        default: null
    },
    user_id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "user"},
    body: {type: String, required: true}
})

const comment = mongoose.model('comment', commentSchema)
```

If a document is a direct comment there will be "postId" otherwise comment replies are identified by "parentCommentId".

The aggregate method looks like this:

```
comment.aggregate([
        {
            $match: { postId : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(postid) }
        },
        {            
            $lookup: {
                    from: "users",
                    localField: "user_id",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "user"
            },    
        },
        {
            $project: {
              "_id": 1,
              "body": 1,
              "postId":1,
              "likes":1,
              "liked": {$in: [ req.authData.nUser._id, "$liked_by" ]},
              "parentCommentId": 1,
              "user._id": 1,
              "user.fullname": 1,
            }
        }
        ]).sort({"_id":-1})
        .exec((err, comments)=>{
            ....          
        })
```

I'm trying to get the reply count with each comment using the aggregate method.

The output now is:

```
{
    "comments": [
        {
            "_id": "635770d1a21b718afae35bcb",
            "postId": "6356c9a1de27e4671fde118a",
            "likes": 0,
            "body": "This is a comment",
            "user": [
                {
                    "_id": "6343e1e2f72a56b1795a4c37",
                    "fullname": "John Doe"
                }
            ],
            "liked": false,
        },
        {
         ....
        }
    ]
}
```

The output should be:

```
{
    "comments": [
        {
            "_id": "635770d1a21b718afae35bcb",
            "postId": "6356c9a1de27e4671fde118a",
            "likes": 0,
            "body": "This is a comment",
            "user": [
                {
                    "_id": "6343e1e2f72a56b1795a4c37",
                    "fullname": "John Doe"
                }
            ],
            "liked": false,
            "replyCount": 0
        },
        {
         ....
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what was your expected output

Comment: You can normalize the schema into two separate schemas LikeSchema and CommentSchema. It will eliminate the nesting of objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is best way for `comments & replies` approach, try it.

```
// Comment Model Schema

const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    postId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'post'
    },
    commenter: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    },
    comment: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    likes: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'user',
        },
    ],
    edited: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    reply: [
        {
            commenter: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'user',
            },
            comment: {
                type: String,
            },
            like: [
                {
                    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'Profile',
                },
            ],
            edited: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            },
            createdAt: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now()
            },
            updatedAt: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now()
            }
        }
    ]
}, {
    timestamps: true
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('comments', commentSchema)
```

In the `get api`, you can add total_likes through `likes.length` and using the length you can come to know `liked: true` or `false`

Comment: This nesting would limit the number of replies by document size..

Comment: This is called `Embedded Sub-Document`. You can use it based on your needs.

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the comment replies count from the schema that I use?